# String(*) type in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, types

I am given a DLL which I want to use in a VB.NET project. I am unable to call a function due to the function signature. The function looks like

```
DLL_Function(Param1 As String, ByRef Param2 As String(*))
```

What type of variable am I supposed to pass to this function for `Param2`? I tried using a normal array, but that does not work as Visual Studio complains that `String()` cannot be converted into `String(*)`. I also tried creating a variable with type `String(*)` but this is not a type known to VB. I cannot make a VB.NET function with this signature either. The DLL is not written in VB.NET, is it possible that this type just is not available and therefore the function cannot be used?

Comment: It is a non-conformal array, most typically because the array's lower bound is 1 instead of 0.  Creating such an array is possible with Array.CreateInstance() but you'd have to get the declaration changed from String(*) to Array or Object to make the call.  Maybe that's easy, but you haven't provided any leads.  MethodInfo.Invoke() is the backdoor.

Comment: The DLL is external, so I do not have any influence over that. I'll try the Method.Invoke, thanks!